# IAM Custom Role for Inserting to Specific BigQuery Dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

I have several customer projects that write analytic events into a BigQuery dataset. The setup is organised like this:

1) Each GCP project has its own set of GCP resources and some of them report analytics using BigQuery insert API.

2) There's a single "Main Analytics" project that intakes all the data from the different projects in a standardised table (all projects write in the same data format).

I've created a custom IAM role in "Main Analytics" with the required permissions to execute a row insert operation:

```
bigquery.datasets.get
bigquery.tables.get
bigquery.tables.updateData
```

For every customer project I've created a unique service account with the above role. This allows each resource in any project to authenticate and insert rows (but not create/delete tables).

**Problem**: What I really want to do is limit the service accounts to write only to a specific dataset that intakes all the data. The above IAM role allows the service account to list all datasets/tables in the "Main Analytics" project and to insert into them.

If I use [dataset permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#dataset-primitive-roles) - add the service account email as a user to the dataset ACL - then it would have to be `WRITER` dataset role which would allow the service account to create & delete tables in the dataset which is too broad.

Combining the IAM role with the dataset permissions results in a union so the wider `WRITER` permission take effect over the narrower IAM role.

Anyway I can configure roles/permissions to allow each service account to insert and only-insert to a specific dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the `bigquery.datasets.get`  permission from the custom IAM role so that they can’t list all the datasets, and then in the dataset's permissions give the `READER` role instead of `WRITER` to the user for that specific dataset.

Comment: I think that BigQuery.datasets.get is required when using SDK like Node JS: dataset(‘dataset’).table(‘table’).insert(). If I remember correctly, SDK will throw an unauthorised error if that permission is missing.

Comment: I've tested it with the Node.js client library in particular and I was able to access that specific dataset (which I shared with the service account as "reader") while getting an authorisation error for all the other datasets ("Access Denied: Dataset <project>:<not-shared-dataset>: The user <service account> does not have bigquery.datasets.get permission for dataset <project><not-shared-dataset>)

Comment: verified working as expected. Its not a full solution as what I really want is "insert-only to this dataset" but better than my current solution as the service account cannot list all datasets in the project and cannot delete any tables.